# Introduction to AI

Tags: functions, artificial-intelligence

In the book ***Introduction to artificial intelligence*** Ertel asks this question (exercise 1.5(a)):

> Why is a deterministic agent with memory not a function from the set
> of all inputs to the set of all outputs, in the mathematical sense?

I don't even know why this statement would be true! I mean, I understand that mathematical functions are "pure functions" and thus do not have "side effects." An agent with memory can be viewed as a function with side effects and thus can't be a pure math function. But what prevents from choosing as the set of all inputs the "spacetime" of input? Doing so brings back the agent with memory to a pure function which can be represented as a mathematical functions!

Am I missing something or is what I say correct?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure that I am understanding your question, so I could be totally missing
the point that you are trying to make.  First of all, I am unable to decipher the
phrase "spacetime of input".  Therefore, I can only assume that the inputs to
the AI are as follows: (1) Reality, as it currently exists at the time that the
AI is going to be launched. ...see next comment

Comment: (2) A deterministic conclusion for what reality will
be at any time point in the future.  This conclusion would have to include 
a conclusion of exactly how the AI will be affecting reality, and (simultaneously)
how reality will be affecting AI's memory and its *programming*.  Based on these ideas,
I see nothing untenable in the idea that all of the future behavior of the AI
is pre-determined, therefore merely a function of reality at the time that the AI
is "turned on".

Comment: spacetime would be the space of input $I$ in time $T$ $I\times T$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing more about this statements context, here is the point I imagine the author is trying to make:

The behavior of a deterministic agent with memory evolves as its internal state (i.e. memory) evolves. Mathematical functions do not have an evolving internal state in this sense.  A mathematical function must satisfy the requirement that every input is mapped to only one output. Consider the function $f$ from input set $I$ to output set $O$. $f$ cannot take an element of $I$ to more than one element of $O$ and still be considered a function in the mathematical sense.

However, a deterministic agent with memory state $B$ might map some input $a$ to output $b$ while, at a later time, that same deterministic agent with memory state $C$ could map input $a$ to output $c$. This is inconsistent with the mathematical notion of a function.

Comment: +1 interesting analysis

Comment: Ok that I understand that. What a don't get is why the imput history could not be considered as an imput if we chose the domain to be $I\times T$

Comment: @NicolasLussier-Clément You could do this. But now, your deterministic agent no long has access to any memory; instead, it's taking all of the data contained in what used to be it's memory as input from an outside source. It's behavior can now be described as a mathematical function, but at the cost of it's evolving internal state, which is arguably what makes AI interesting in the first place.

Comment: I guess that is it !! It must be what the author had in mind then !